# UITextfield cursor error with a placeholder

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a simple uitextfield that I create in a empty project. I set only a placeholder and textalign to center. In this video:

https://vid.me/5UR1

you can see that the cursor from centered position go to left for a small time and come back to centered and this is very annoying.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'd have to guess that you would need to implement your own placeholder... Have you seen it work differently elsewhere?

Comment: Uhmmm this is the first time that I need a similar behaviour and not I'm trying to use the "basic" uitextfield and its placeholder

Comment: did you find the solution?